# Using jquery to add html depending on other html

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code as below

```
<div class="box coursebox">
  <h3 class="main"><a title="GCSE English" href="http://vle.sheffcol.ac.uk/moodle/course/view.php?id=1656">GCSE English</a> </h3>
</div>
<div class="box coursebox">
  <h3 class="main"> <a title="GCSE Maths" href="http://vle.sheffcol.ac.uk/moodle/course/view.php?id=1526">GCSE Maths</a> </h3>
  <div class="assign overview">
     <div class="name"> Assignment: <a title="Assignment" href="http://vle.sheffcol.ac.uk/moodle/mod/assign/view.php?id=59691">Algebra assignment 1</a> </div>
     <div class="name"> Assignment: <a title="Assignment" href="http://vle.sheffcol.ac.uk/moodle/mod/assign/view.php?id=59691">Algebra assignment 1</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do it use jquery to add the following bit of HTML

```
<span class="button" id="button">Show activities</span>
```

to each coursebox after the H3 tag IF there is a div.overview as a child.

Firstly, is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, try this:

```
$(".coursebox").has("div.overview").each(function() {
    $("h3", $(this)).after("<span class=\"button\" id=\"button\">Show activities</span>");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GrWFB/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
$(".coursebox").has("div.overview").each(function(){
  var $span = $("<span>")
      .addClass('button')
      .attr('id','button')
      .text('Show activities');

    $span.insertAfter($(this).find('H3.main'))

});​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var spanEl = $('<span/>', {
 id: "button",
 class: "button",
 text: "Show activities"
});
$("h3", $(this)).after(spanEl);
```